# jQuery to find previous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table

```
<table>
<tr class="ligneI">
<td class="col2b"><input type="text" id="desc" class="calcule"></td>
<td class="col2b"><input type="text" id="price" class="calcule"></td>
<td class="calculated_price">220.00</td>
<td class="calculated_price">1800.00</td>
<td><a title="" class="picto06 deleteLink" id="deleteLink1" href="#" onclick="resetfields(this);">delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="ligneI">
<td class="col2b"><input type="text" id="desc" class="calcule"></td>
<td class="col2b"><input type="text" id="price" class="calcule"></td>
<td class="calculated_price">87.00</td>
<td class="calculated_price">40.00</td>
<td><a title="" class="picto06 deleteLink" id="deleteLink2" href="#" onclick="resetfields(this);">delete</a></td>
...
```

and I would like to reset the entire  when i click on a delete link.

I tried to do something like this:

```
function resetfields(obj)
{
    $(this).parent().prevAll('td.calcule').html('&nbsp;');
    $(this).parent().prevAll('td input.calcule').val('');
}
```

but only the first line erase the two first  befor my link.
Someone can help me please.

Ps : excuse my english

Comment: It's generally considered good practice to separate your Javascript completely from your markup (just like separating markup from CSS). In that case, you'd bind the `onclick` handlers in your Javascript code, something like this: `$('a.deleteLink').click(resetFields);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td.calculated_price').html('&nbsp;');
$(this).closest('tr').find('td input.calcule').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('td.calculated_price').html(""); //doing parent().parent() to get to TR
$(this).parent().parent().find('td.calcule').val("");
```

HTH

Comment: thanks,
this code works great
$(this).parent().parent().find('td.calculated_price').html(""); 
$(this).parent().parent().find('tdinput.calcule').val("");